# Undefined Index Issue and Error return

Tags: javascript, php, debugging

**Marked as fixed!!!**

I was missing vat_rate in my MySQL business database.  This was causing both issues.  Thanks Nytrix and Grimbode both for the swift and walk through support, much appreciated! :)

---

I'm getting an undefined index issue on line 16...

```
<?php
class Business extends Application {

private $_table = 'business';

public function getBusiness() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->_table}`
            WHERE `id` = 1";
    return $this->db->fetchOne($sql);
}



public function getVatRate() {
    $business = $this->getBusiness();
    return $business['vat_rate'];
}
}
```

How can I fix it?  Thanks.

Also, I'm getting an error pop-up when I click my add to basket and remove from basket links, which is called from basket.js on line 13 and 14.  I don't know how to fix that either, but think it may have something to do with the above?

Regards

Edit;  Thinking I've done a var_dump correctly(?), this is what is shown for $business when I wrote

```
<?php var_dump($business); ?>
```

in my _header.php file to echo the array (I say that though with no knowledge!).

Notice: Undefined variable: business in /Users/ashleysmith/Documents/Website Tests/Z - Work from this/ecommerce/template/_header.php on line 68
NULL

Here's all the relevant code as far as I know...

**Business.php**

```
<?php
class Business extends Application {

    private $_table = 'business';

    public function getBusiness() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->_table}`
                WHERE `id` = 1";
        return $this->db->fetchOne($sql);
    }



    public function getVatRate() {
        $business = $this->getBusiness();
        return $business['vat_rate'];
    }
 }
```

**basket_small_refresh.php**

```
<?php
require_once("../inc/autoload.php");
$objBasket = new Basket();
$out = array();
$out['bl_ti'] = $objBasket->_number_of_items;
$out['bl_st'] = number_format($objBasket->_sub_total, 2);
$out['bl_vat'] = number_format($objBasket->_vat, 2);
$out['bl_total'] = number_format($objBasket->_total, 2);
echo json_encode($out);
```

**basket_left.php**

```
<div id="small_basket">

<?php $objBasket = new Basket(); ?>

    <p class="your_bas">Your Basket</p>

    <dl id="basket_left">

        <dt>No. of items:</dt>
            <dd class="bl_ti"><span><?php echo $objBasket->_number_of_items; ?></span></dd>

        <dt>Sub-total:</dt>
            <dd class="bl_st">&pound;<span><?php echo number_format($objBasket->_sub_total, 2); ?></span></dd>

        <dt>VAT (<span><?php echo $objBasket->_vat_rate; ?></span>%):</dt>
            <dd class="bl_vat">&pound;<span><?php echo number_format($objBasket->_vat, 2); ?></span></dd>

        <dt>Total (inc):</dt>
            <dd class="bl_total">&pound;<span><?php echo number_format($objBasket->_total, 2); ?></span></dd>
    </dl>



    <p class="check_button">
        <a href="/?page=basket">View Basket</a> | 
        <a href="/?page=checkout">Checkout</a>
    </p>

</div>
```

**basket.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../inc/autoload.php');
if (isset($_POST['job']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
$out = array();

$job = $_POST['job'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$objCatalogue = new Catalogue();
$product = $objCatalogue->getProduct($id);

if (!empty($product)) {

    switch($job) {

        case 0:
        Session::removeItem($id);
        $out['job'] = 1;
        break;

        case 1:
        Session::setItem($id);
        $out['job'] = 0;
        break;

        }
        echo json_encode($out);

    }
}
```

**Basket.php**

```
<?php
 class Basket {
  public $_inst_catalogue;
  public $_empty_basket;
  public $_vat_rate;
  public $_number_of_items;
  public $_sub_total;
  public $_vat;
  public $_total;


   public function __construct() {

    $this->_inst_catalogue = new Catalogue();
    $this->_empty_basket = empty($_SESSION['basket']) ? true : false;

    $objBusiness = new Business();
    $this->_vat_rate = $objBusiness->getVatRate();

    $this->noItems();
    $this->subtotal();
    $this->vat();
    $this->total();

  }


  public function noItems() {
    $value = 0;
    if (!$this->_empty_basket) {
        foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $key => $basket) {
            $value += $basket['qty'];
        }
    }
    $this->_number_of_items = $value;
  }



    public function subtotal() {
      $value = 0;
      if (!$this->_empty_basket) {
        foreach($_SESSION['basket'] as $key => $basket) {
            $product = $this->_inst_catalogue->getProduct($key);
            $value += ($basket['qty'] * $product['price']); 
          }
      }     
      $this->_sub_total = round($value, 2);
    }



    public function vat() {
      $value = 0;
      if (!$this->_empty_basket) {
        $value = ($this->_vat_rate * ($this->_sub_total / 100));
      }     
      $this->_vat = round($value, 2);   
    }



    public function total() {
      $this->_total = round(($this->_sub_total + $this->_vat), 2);  
    }
    public static function activeButton($sess_id) {
      if(isset($_SESSION['basket'][$sess_id])) {
        $id = 0;
        $label = "Remove From Basket";
      } else {
        $id = 1;
        $label = "Add To Basket";
      }
      $out = "<a href=\"#\" class=\"add_to_basket";
      $out .= $id == 0 ? " red" : null;
      $out .= "\" rel=\"";
      $out .= $sess_id."_".$id;
      $out .= "\">{$label}</a>";
      return $out; 
      }
  }
```

**basket.js**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    function refreshSmallBasket() {

        $.ajax({
        url: '/mod/basket_small_refresh.php', 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                $("#basket_left ." + k + " span").text(v);
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Error occured");
        }

        });

    }

    if ($(".add_to_basket").length > 0) {
        $(".add_to_basket").click(function() {

        var trigger = $(this);
        var param = trigger.attr("rel");
        var item = param.split("_");

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: '/mod/basket.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ({ id : item[0], job : item[1] }),
            success: function(data) {
                var new_id = item[0] + '_' + data.job;
                if (data.job != item[1]) {
                    if (data.job == 0) {
                        trigger.attr("rel", new_id);
                        trigger.text("Remove From Basket");
                        trigger.addClass("red");
                    } else {
                        trigger.attr("rel", new_id);
                        trigger.text("Add To Basket");
                        trigger.removeClass("red");
                        }
                        refreshSmallBasket();
                    }

                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert("Error occured"); 
                }

            });
            return false;

        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code as well instead of just providing a link.

Comment: It sounds like `$business['vat_rate']` doesn't exist. Do a `var_dump` on `$business` and include that with your question.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it's not set (the variable), but I'm a complete newbie and don't know how to do that var_dump.  Sorry, can you kindly explain?  Thanks! :)

Comment: Line 18 and 19 in Basket.php

$objBusiness = new Business();
  $this->_vat_rate = $objBusiness->getVatRate();

Comment: Code added @Grimbode :)

Comment: @AshleySmith I'll take a look at it in a bit. ^^

Comment: Cheers Grimbode, "appreciate everyone's help with this".  I've totally no clue on the undefined error and alert error pop-ups clicking the basket buttons... from the basket.js.  Learning from a tutorial video, but things are missing obviously from their code/teaching :(

Comment: Don't know why people keep downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you are selecting everything `*` from you're table defined as `$_table = "business"`. You want to select the 'vat_rate' column that may not exists in the returnd array. Here for you checked with `var_dump` how you're array looks. If you want to know how to select a value from that array please look on the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php OR http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp (mabey a bit simpler explained)

Comment: I get NULL for the var_dump, which I wrote as <?php var_dump($business); ?> in my header.  Is that correct syntax?

Comment: If I place [0], I get the error... Undefined offset: 0

Comment: That was just a guess, i don't know how you're array looks like. Please add to you're question the result of: `var_dump($business);` Then we know (and you) what you're array looks like, or if it even is an array.

Comment: I edited, and get this... Notice: Undefined variable: business in /Users/ashleysmith/Documents/Website Tests/Z - Work from this/ecommerce/template/_header.php on line 68 NULL  ...but I'm not sure if I wrote the var_dump correctly as I've never done it before.  Newbie! :)

Comment: Just copy my `var_dump` code. And put it in the getVatRate() as it is able to get the variable `$business` there.

Comment: I placed var_dump($business) within the getVatRate brackets on line 14, and get... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /Users/ashleysmith/Documents/Website Tests/Z - Work from this/ecommerce/classes/Business.php on line 14

Comment: Ok, so you have made a query. You fetch a result of it, this will return an array right? You want to check if this result (array) is an array or how it looks. You do that by putting you're array in the function `var_dump()`, this variable needs to be accesible from that point.

Comment: I get what you mean by wanting to check it to see if anything is called, but that's as far as my understanding goes re php, so I really don't know where to place the code you're referencing (on which file listed) nor what to actually write?  Sorry for the newbie status. :(

Comment: I've edited my answer, and don't worry about you're skill. I would recommend to not directly follow tutorials but first learn `php` in general

Comment: Thanks!  Ok, that pipes out sensitive string information from my MySQL database, such as name, e-mail, address, and website fields.  This variable as far as I know should be calling the vat_rate (a percentage) used to offset my shopping "Basket.php" price on line 57.  $value = ($this->_vat_rate * ($this->_sub_total / 100));  ...It shouldn't be calling anything from that MySQL business database.

Comment: I've edited my answer, hopefully this will clear the problem. If it doesn't please show the var)dump with other values.

Comment: I'm missing vat_rate in the business database!  Damn!  I must've removed that as I'm not adding any tax for products.  Thank you for walking me through this, that dump definitely helped, and I imported the tutorial sql file again to check what was missing.  Great!  That fixed the add/remove basket buttons too! :)  @Nytrix, you rock!!!

Comment: No problem! `var_dump` is like magic, always use it if there is something wrong with array's or even strings.

Comment: Good call, bookmarked!  Onto the next, gotta figure out how to add "empty the shopping basket"... :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Marked as fixed!!!

I was missing vat_rate in my MySQL business database. This was causing both issues. Thanks Nytrix and Grimbode both for the swift and walk through support, much appreciated! :)